# How to determine output folder of dnu/dotnet publish

Tags: dnx, coreclr, dotnet-cli

When I publish my project with

`dotnet publish`

it outputs to a folder

`bin/Debug/dnxcore50/osx.10.11-x64/publish`

(or perhaps the Release equivalent)

Is it possible to determine this folder location for a postpublish script specified in the project.json file?

Answer (score 12):

Thanks to fast response on the dotnet/cli gitter channel, you can. The following variables are available:

```
%publish:ProjectPath%
%publish:Configuration%
%publish:OutputPath%
%publish:TargetFramework%
%publish:FullTargetFramework%
%publish:Runtime%
```

[Source](https://github.com/dotnet/cli/blob/rel/1.0.0/src/dotnet/commands/dotnet-publish/PublishCommand.cs#L106)

And here are the ones for pre/postcompile:

```
%compile:TargetFramework%
%compile:FullTargetFramework%
%compile:Configuration%
%compile:OutputFile%
%compile:OutputDir%
%compile:ResponseFile%
%compile:RuntimeOutputDir%
%compile:RuntimeIdentifier%
%compile:CompilerExitCode%     // postcompile only
```

[Source](https://github.com/dotnet/cli/blob/rel/1.0.0/src/dotnet/commands/dotnet-compile/ManagedCompiler.cs#L163)

Comment: These should be documented somewhere... Anywhere! `project.json` is a black box unless one can find the source code and analyse it.

Comment: @BradRobinson I don't understand exactly how to use these variables. I'm able to display for example OutputPath with `<Message Text="$(OutputPath)"/>` but not your %compile:OutputPath%.
Because I'd like to know how to get the REAL OutputPath, if I display it, I get _.\bin_ instead of _.\bin\Debug\net461\win7-x64_

Comment: @JérômeMével The above variables are for use in your `project.json` file. I don't believe there is way of resolving `bin\Debug\net461\win7-x64` from MSBuild. However using `%compile:RuntimeOutputDir%` in `project.json` will resolve to `D:\...\<PROJECT>\bin\Debug\net461\win7-x64`

Comment: Ho cool thank you, I didn't think I could finish the job using dotnet cli

Comment: @Robula I just found the full project.json schema, it might be useful [link](http://json.schemastore.org/project)

Comment: @JérômeMével you absolute legend for finding that schema!! Much help! :)

Comment: @JérômeMével it does not have the complete list of variables that you can use

Comment: @Dealdiane anyway project.json will be gone by the end of this year so better not spend to much time and efforts on it